# Post a form after javascript check

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I would like to send a form after javascript validation in  `validateLengths()` function.
If I fill a form action the form is send anyway if I don't specify `javascript:void(0)`

Here is my code so far...

Currently I'm just able to alert "submit form".

Sorry, I'm a noob in javascript.

Thank you for any related information.
Have a nice day.
Nicolas.

```js
function validateLengths() {
    let fnameCap = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    let lnameCap = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    
    if (fnameCap.length < 4 ) {
        alert("First name  must be atleast 4 characters. ");
        return false;
    }
    if (lnameCap.length < 6) {
        alert("Last name  must be atleast 6 characters. ");
        return false;
    }
    if(fnameCap.length >= 4 && lnameCap.length >= 6){
        alert ("submit form"); // don't know how to send form here
    }
}
function capitalize(){
    let first = document.getElementById("firstName");
    let last = document.getElementById("lastName");
    let fcapitalized = first.value.toUpperCase();
    let lcapitalized = last.value.toUpperCase();
    first.value = (fcapitalized);
    last.value = (lcapitalized);
    validateLengths();
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:void(0)" id="theForm" title="form1">
      <input name="firstName" type="text" id="firstName" value="At least 4 chars">
      <br>
      
      <input name="lastName" type="text" id="lastName" value="At least 6 chars">
      
      <br>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="javascript:capitalize()">
    </form>
```

Comment: What do you want to do with your data after validation? Maybe post request?

Comment: @Mithat Ercan send it to another page to retrieve datas (a form so)